# Anyone know what script it is? Trying to encode but alway error

Tags: encryption

did anyone know what script it this? so difficult to know what formatted used for this script.

```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```

im try to deobfuscated the script but still the string error. Please if anyone know or how to decode this script. Or a method to find out what encryption is used. I wanna know what contains. Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like a base64 string

Comment: however, it seems encrypted or something

Comment: trying to encode but the problem from end of string..

Comment: It Base64 decoded without error to binary data, probably encryoted data.

Answer (score 0):

It's [Base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), from the looks of it.

I tried decoding it and got garbage data back, so either the string is incomplete, is not base64, OR (more likely, in my opinion) the script does something to the output of that base64 (such as decrypting it, maybe it's encrypted data stored as base64?) to make it readable.

Comment: 1. It Base64 decodes without error to binary data. 2. There is a difference between "garbage data", whatever that is, and binary data. Base64 is generally used to encode binary data into displayable ASCII characters.

Comment: @zaph well, i wasn't sure what it was, i was expecting an identifiable file, i wrote the output and used the [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) utility to try and fingerprint the format and it didn't know what it was, so i said garbage data, perhaps not the best phrasing.